# Upgrade node specs for existing Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, vmware

I just upgraded the RAM from 16GB to 32GB for all VM nodes of existing cluster.

But `kubectl get nodes` still shows 16GB
per node
memory, how to make kubernetes re-read the sepcs?

Comment: I would have expected `kubelet` to pick up that change when it restarted; what does `docker info` show? And are you running `kubelet` in a container?

Comment: Did kubelet even restart I wonder.

Comment: No , I need to run a kubectl command that re-read node specs for all the nodes , if its a thousand node cluster then I will ssh into  every node and restart kubelet? instead kubelet should should keep reading node specs in a loop every few seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart Kubelet does the trick but its not practial in case of larger clusters.

```
$ kubectl get nodes node-02 -o yaml | grep mem
    memory: 16145384Ki
    memory: 16247784Ki
    message: kubelet has sufficient memory available
```

After restart:

```
$ kubectl get nodes node-02 -o yaml | grep mem
    memory: 32922600Ki
    memory: 33025000Ki
    message: kubelet has sufficient memory available
```